# Cucumber options (Command line) no longer works with newer version of cucumber (io.cucumber)?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

Currently the following command would work when attempting to run tests via the command line window however since updating to io.cucumber from info.cakes it no longer seems to work?

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags @login"
```

Exception message:

```
Sep 17, 2019 5:18:37 PM cucumber.runtime.FeaturePathFeatureSupplier get
WARNING: No features found at classpath:runners
```

However running tests directly from the runner class works:

```
package runners;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(features = { "classpath:features" }, glue = {
        "stepDefinitions"}, monochrome = true, tags = {"@login"}, dryRun = false,
        plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/cucumber.json"})

    public class MainRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
}
```

Cucumber version:

```
<cucumber.version>4.7.2</cucumber.version>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
```

You are mixing JUnit and TestNG. You should in a single class use either JUnit or TestNG. Not both.

Comment: thanks for the reply but the testng extension / import is required so that I can trigger my tests via a testng.xml class; enabling me to run my tests concurrently.

Comment: Then you should remove/replace the junit imports with testng ones.

Comment: ok @mpkorstanje, do you know how I would handle, import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber | @RunWith(Cucumber.class)?

Comment: If you are running with TestNG you don't need @RunWith(Cucumber.class). Thats for JUnit.